# Facebook Batch Request Returns Empty Bodies

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-batch-request

I am working on Facebook Marketing API and in a single batch request creating 1 Ad Campaign with 4 Ad Sets, in each Ad Set by 1 Ad creative and based on each Ad creative 5 Ads in each Ad Set. I have no problem with it at all and everything was cerated but response has a lot of empties bodies.

I need to get all ids of each created Ad Campaign, Ad Sets, Ad Creatives and Ads. Total objects should be 29. But I am getting in response only ids for Ads (last level)

Is there a way to force send all bodies in response or without using single requests get all info I need?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The empty response bodies seem to be a bug on the server side.

As a workaround, you can get the Campaign and AdSet id from the ads. You can set redownload=true in the API request when creating the ads to get these info.

Comment: Thanks! It did the trick, not everywhere but at least on Ad level I can see Ad creative id and Ad Set Id! The rest is fine, I can figure it out.